# how to find keyword inside a string or array, in php?

Tags: php, arrays, search

i have a string:

```
$string = "test1 - test2 - kw: test - key: 123 - test5";
```

and im trying to get this result:

```
kw = test;
key = 123;
```

I've tried spiting the string:

```
$array = explode("-", $str );
print_r($array);
```

and the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  test1 
    [1] =>  test2
    [2] =>  kw: test
    [3] =>  key: 123
    [4] =>  test5
)
```

from here i would like to do something like:

```
$str = 'kw:';
if ( in_array ( $str , $array ) ) {
    echo 'It exists';
} else {
    echo 'Does not exist';
}
```

or

```
$kw = array_search('kw:', $array );
```

but `$array` is an arrays of array.

im  not sure how to proceed from here.

any ideas? Is there another way of extracting those words?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using preg_match this becomes really easy:

```
$string = "test1 - test2 - kw: test - key: 123 - test5";
$results = preg_match('/.*?(kw: (.*?) - )(key: (.*?) -).*/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Should return an array of matches that correspond to what you are looking for...

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(43) "test1 - test2 - kw: test - key: 123 - test5"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "kw: test - "
  [2]=>
  string(4) "test"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "key: 123 -"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "123"
}
```

For more information regarding regular expressions (Very powerful tool):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Close: You need `preg_match_all()` if you want to find more than one match and you need to pass $matches as the third parameter

Comment: well, this is a success. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a loop that looks for the substrings `kw:` and `key:` in the

```
$string = "test1 - test2 - kw: test - key: 123 - test5";
$array = explode("-", $string);

foreach ($array as $part) {
  if (substr(trim($part), 0, 3) == 'kw:') {
    list($kw, $kwval) = explode(' ' , trim($part));
    echo "kw: $kwval\n";
  }
  if (substr(trim($part), 0, 4) == 'key:') {
    list($key, $keyval) = explode(' ' , trim($part));
    echo "key: $keyval\n";
  }
}


// Output:
// kw: test
// key: 123
```

Comment: @Patrioticcow because you have the wrong variable in the first `explode()` call. use `$string` instead of `$str`. I found and fixed that in one of my edits.

Answer (score 1):

```
php > $string="test1 - test2 - kw: test - key: 123 - test5";
php > $pattern="/\ \-\ (\w+)\:\s([^\s]+)/";
php > echo preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);
2
php > print_r($matches);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  - kw: test
            [1] =>  - key: 123
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => kw
            [1] => key
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
            [1] => 123
        )

)
php >
```

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant, but:

```
$string = "test1 - test2 - kw: test - key: 123 - test5"; 

$array = explode(" - ", $string);

foreach ($array as $v) {
    if (strstr($v,"kw: ")) {
        $kw = substr($v,4);
    }
    if (strstr($v,"key: ")) {
        $key = substr($v,5);
    }
}

echo "kw = " . $kw;
echo "key = " . $key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at substr()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

You wouldn't have to explode your String